# Removing duplicate items from an array using C language

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, unique

Removing duplicate items from a sorted array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int arr[12] = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5 };
    int temp[12];
    int i, j, k, n = 12;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1]) {
            temp[j] = arr[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    temp[j] = arr[n - 1];

    for (k = 0; k <= j; k++) {
        printf("%d\n", temp[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
6356652
1955753237
1956070172
6356716
1955750536
8
1955687363
1955687354
1
2
3
4
5

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.014 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I do not want these numbers to be printed out:

```
6356652
1955753237
1956070172
6356716
1955750536
8
1955687363
1955687354
```

Comment: You don't initialize `j` or `temp[12]`

Answer (score 4):

You did not initialize the variable `j`. So using the uninitialized variable invokes undefined behavior.

It is better to form the array without duplicates in one loop instead of splitting the loop into a loop and one more statement after the loop.

You can write a separate function for example the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t remove_copy( const int a[], int b[], size_t n )
{
    size_t j = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( i == 0 || a[i] != b[j-1] ) b[j++] = a[i];
    }

    return j;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5 };
    int b[sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a )];
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    size_t n = remove_copy( a, b, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", b[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Weither this works (or not) depends on the data in the 'a[]' being is assending order.  This dependency is a serious short coming of the algorithm in the answer

Comment: @user3629249 You are wrong. The algorithm works also for data sorted in the descending order.

Comment: @user3629249: the algorithm works for any sorting order: ascending, descending, alphabetical, pixel density... the only requirement is that all duplicates be adjacent, which is the case for all regular sorting orders.

Answer (score 1):

Your code and logic is correct. But you did a mistake by not intializing `j = 0`. Because of that you were getting some gibberish values. So, I corrected and executed it and got correct answer.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr[12] = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5 };
    int temp[12];
    int i, j = 0, k, n = 12;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1]) {
            temp[j] = arr[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    temp[j] = arr[n - 1];

    for (k = 0; k <= j; k++) {
        printf("%d\n", temp[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```